# MuleStudio Connector Example The attribute comments is undefined for the annotation type Generated

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm getting the following error after importing the project from Maven POM to MuleStudio.

```
The attribute comments is undefined for the annotation type Generated
```

Please help to resolve this issue.
My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-connector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-module</packaging>
    <name>Hello Connector</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.mule.tools.devkit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-devkit-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.3</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
        <mockito.version>1.8.2</mockito.version>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <category>Community</category>
        <licensePath>LICENSE.md</licensePath>
        <devkit.studio.package.skip>false</devkit.studio.package.skip>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git://github.com:mulesoft/hello-connector.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:mulesoft/hello-connector.git</developerConnection>
        <url>http://github.com/mulesoft/hello-connector</url>
    </scm>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0-v20070426</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used mule-devkit-partent version 3.4.2 to make it work.